# Creating hosting accounts in WHM on a single IP

Tags: web-hosting, vps, ip-address

I've just purchased a VPS with the hope of transferring multiple shared hosting accounts onto it. The problem is that I've only got 2 IP addresses with my VPS.

I can create an account and assign it an IP address, but once I've done this once, I can't do it again. (1 IP address is my main root WHM IP, the other is my new hosting account IP).

Can I create multiple hosting accounts and use the same IP? How would I manage multiple hosting accounts in this way?

The domain for this hosting account has been purchased by the client, and they hold it (can't transfer for 60 days), so I need to adjust the DNS settings to redirect to my newly created hosting area - how can I do this without a dedicated IP address?

Comment: You should be able to do this, although I'm unsure of whether you would need to configure anything in your case. This is what [shared hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_web_hosting_service) is - name based virtual hosting. On a shared host it is common for 100's (sometimes 1000's!) of sites to share 1 IP address.

Comment: I agree with @w3d - did that solve your problem @Daniel-Hanly?

Comment: Well, @w3d's comment doesn't offer a solution, just says that it can be done! It gave me great relief to know it can be done, but I still have no idea how to do it!

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/multiple-sites-per-ip-240471.html - "You would need to create account A as a reseller account, but then you'd need to use WHM > Resellers > Manage reseller's main/shared IP to set that IP as the main shared IP for that reseller's account. Provided you don't allow the reseller any dedicated IP privileges or assign other IPs to that reseller, then all accounts under that reseller should use the reseller's main/shared IP you've set."

Comment: So in WHM, I go to my Resellers list and notice that the root is already a reseller. Does this mean that I can just add any number of user accounts and provided the nameservers on the domains point to my nameservers, all should work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

In WHM, I've got two separate "packages" setup. One for dedicated IP's, and one for Shared IPs. "Dedicated IP" is an option when setting up the Package. So all you should need to do is create a Package called shared-ip or some such, unclick the `Dedicated IP` checkbox when setting it up, and then use that Package for any accounts that you want on the Shared IP.

Answer (score 0):

u can assign a single ip to any number of domains

if u have 2 domains , want to host in single server create vhost in apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site1.com
    ServerAlias site1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
    ##DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/site1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site2.com
    ServerAlias site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
    ##DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/site2
</VirtualHost>
```

- *means wildcard IP and :80 is for port
  u can change that too

If not working

Try adding DNS

In windows : C:\Program Files\system32\drivers\etc
In Linux : /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 site1.com
127.0.0.1 site2.com